# Generating ID for column managed by Hibernate's HiLo algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, hibernate, nhibernate

The situation:

- An existing application uses NHibernate to interact with a SQL Server database. IDs for all tables are generated by NHibernate using its HiLo algorithm, and the tables don't have any identity set (i.e. GeneratedBy().Hilo("1"))
- A second application needs to be able to (infrequently) add rows to one of those tables, but it needs to be able to generate a unique ID that will play nicely with the NHibernate-using application, without having to change how that older application works

The question: How can I replicate the process that NHibernate (and presumably Hibernate) goes through in order to generate one of these IDs? I assume it would involve fetching and incrementing the value in the hibernate_unique_key table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically how I solved the problem:

```
declare @newid int;
set @newid = (select top 1 (@max_lo + 1) * next_hi) from hibernate_unique_key);
update hibernate_unique_key set next_hi = next_hi + 1;
insert into ExampleTable(Id, Column)
values (@newid, @Value);
select @newid;
```

This was using Dapper, and inside a transaction

Since in my case max_lo was just 1, I only "lose" 1 id each time I insert a row this way